# Playing sound nonstop through XIB's?

Tags: ios, audio

Does anyone know how to play a sound (not stopping, always on a loop) through different view controllers (XIB's)? Also I want to be able to stop it at any moment based upon a button click. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).